# Is $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{k}, 2)$ a cover of $(0, 1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, covering-spaces

I was just wondering whether $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{k}, 2)$ is a cover of $(0, 1)$. Intuitively I think that it is because $\frac{1}{k}\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$ so I'll start catching all the numbers near zero as I open up the interval. Please let me know if I'm making a mistake, thank you!

Comment: Sure. For large enough $k$, every $x \in (0,1)$ is in some interval $(\frac 1 k, 2)$. If you want to formally show this, just find the necessary $k$, but I'd say it's quite obvious just at first glance.

Comment: thanks. and I think I can show that $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^n$ doesn't cover $(0, 1)$ because it doesn't contain very small elements of $(0, 1)$, right? for $I_k = (\frac{1}{k}, 2)$.

Comment: no, it should be a cover of $(0,1)$. if the interval were instead $[0,1)$, then this could not be a cover because $0$ is never in the union of $(1/k,2)$.

Comment: how could $\{(\frac{1}{k}, 2)\}_{k=1}^n$ cover $(0, 1)$? I'm starting with $(1, 2)$ and I only take the union up to $(\frac{1}{n}, 2)$. I've missed values extremely close to zero.

Answer (score 2):

We want to show that $(0,1)\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k},2)$.

Fix $z\in(0,1)$. By the Archimedean property, there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<z$. Then $z\in(\frac{1}{N},2)$. It follows that $z\in\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k},2)$, so $(0,1)\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k},2)$.

We are able to make use of the Archimedean property because $z>0$ and $z\neq 0$. If $z=0$, there would not exist and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<0$, so $0$ is never in any set in the union. Zero is however a limit point of the union.